# Send callback from activity to fragment

Tags: android, callback

I have a **view pager** in my Activity. This pager loads 2 fragments (Fragment1 and Fragment2).
My Activity have a button for fetching data from server as a list of my pojo class.
Fragment1 and Fragment2 contains recyclerView.

My question is How do I refresh Fragment1's recyclerView adapter (from my Activity) when information is fetched in my Activity?

I created an interface in my Activity:

```
    public interface IloadCallBack {
    void onLoadAdapter(List<Suser> userList);
}
```

and I have created a setter for this:

```
    public void setIloadCallBack(IloadCallBack iloadCallBack) {
    this.iloadCallBack = iloadCallBack;
}
```

and init it:

```
iloadCallBack.onLoadAdapter(susers);
```

Now, I have make a reference of activity into my fragment but I think this is wrong!! yes? what can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can do refresh recyclerView adapter in fragment 1 from my Activity when information fetched at my activity

You do not need the callback mechanism to pass data to fragment, hosted in activity.

Just create a method in fragment `refreshList`

```
// in fragment
public void refreshList(List<Suser> userList){
      this.userList.clear();// empty list
      this.userList.addAll(userList);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Keep a global reference to fragment instance and invoke `refreshList` from where you receive the response.

```
public class YourActivity...{
    private Fragment fragmentInstance;


    void someMethodReceivedNewList(){
        // where you receive new list in activity
        if(fragmentinstance!=null)
            fragmentinstance.refreshList(userList);

    }

    void someMethodToLoadFragment(){
        fragmentInstance = new YourFragment1();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Communicating from activity to fragment:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
        // Do something here to display that article

        ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Communicating from fragment to activity:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Both are taken from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Feel free to have a look there, they explain everything very well.

Comment: dude plz read my question!! how you can send an Activity by bundle?

Comment: I read your question and I posted an answer. The way to update your fragment through your activity is using the methods I described. Please read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to perform some action when any specific event happens in some other place like if you want to execute any method in your fragment when an event happened in your activity or vice versa, I will suggest you should use EventBus.

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

This is the simple and straightforward solution.

Comment: I need to reference of my Activity. I am using of eventBus but now I need do something in fragment after fetching of data from activity.

Comment: yes , you can do whatever action you want to do , if you use event bus , your event bus function will get to know like the particular event happened , now i want to execute this code , and it will work

Comment: If you want a good event bus check out implementation of event bus via RxAndroid. Other than that, I'd recommend you to go for my posted answer.

Comment: follow this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-the-eventbus-library--cms-22694